# ¿Dónde se usa la exclamación "¡caracoles!"?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, interjecciones

Me acuerdo de que, cuando era niño, vi el programa de niños *Muppets* (en inglés se titula *Muppet Babies*), donde salía la rana René exclamando a cada rato "¡caracoles!".

Luego, viéndolo otra vez en el inglés original, ví que era la traducción de algo como *"sheesh!"*.  Nunca he conocido a un hispanohablante que dijera "¡caracoles!" con ese significado.  ¿Pertenece esta exclamacion a alguna region hispanohablante?

Comment: Como curiosidad, el "sheesh" que mencionas no deja de ser una forma de evitar decir "shit", al igual que expresiones como "caracoles", "carambolas" o incluso "caramba" son formas de evitar decir "carajo" (palabra ya existente en el idioma español en el siglo XVI).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caracoles es una interjección que el DRAE recoge:

> [caracoles](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7ONGehG)
>   1. interj. caramba<sup>1</sup>.

Siguiendo el enlace, llegamos a:

> [caramba<sup>1</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7PSW6o2)
>   1. interjección eufemística usada para expresar extrañeza o enfado.

Así que sí, *¡caracoles!* es una expresión conocida y usada para expresar sorpresa o enfado.

El DRAE no especifica ninguna región en particular, por lo que podemos asumir que se usa por todo el ámbito del castellano. En España no es nada extraña, si bien nunca oí a nadie usándola: se usa en dibujos animados y, especialmente, libros para niños.
Sería interesante saber si en otras regiones se usa también solo en este contexto.

---

*Caracoles* is indeed an interjection that DRAE recognises:

> [caracoles](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7ONGehG)
>   1. interj. caramba<sup>1</sup>.

And then:

> [caramba<sup>1</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7PSW6o2)
>   1. interjección eufemística usada para expresar extrañeza o enfado.

So yes, *¡caracoles!* is a rather childish but known way to express surprise or annoyance.

As you see, DRAE does not specify any region in particular, so we can assume it is known everywhere. In Spain it is well known, even though I have never seen anybody using it: it is used, instead, in books or cartoons for kids.

Answer (score 1):

Usada especialmente junto con otras similares en el contexto de doblaje del inglés al audio latino para evitar posibles censuras