# Origen de ¡caracoles! como interjección

Tags: interjecciones

Repitiendo una canción de Les Luthiers (Las majas del bergantín), oía como la palabra caracoles se volvía una interjección a mitad de una charla. Ya se había realizado [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18384/d%C3%B3nde-se-usa-la-exclamaci%C3%B3n-caracoles) un acercamiento al tema y buscando en el mapa de diccionarios aparece desde hace unos 100 años (desde la versión de 1925). Su significado de "caramba" daría a entender que es una especie de eufemismo utilizado desde inicios del siglo pasado. No puedo confirmar a partir del CORDE, debido que el término caracoles suele usarse más como plural de caracol y se dificulta saber cuando es interjección, por lo que el origen de la palabra no me termina de quedar claro

Answer (score 3):

### Carajo

> Lugar situado en lo alto del palo mayor de las carabelas españolas. Un puesto de vigilancia donde se exponía a la lluvia, al frío y a los vientos. Cuando alguien cometía una falta lo castigaban mandándolo al carajo.

[image]

<sub>*[Twitter](https://twitter.com/Cuauhtemoc_1521/status/1030955676313563136) e imagen de [exponav.org](https://www.exponav.org/el-carajo-de-la-vela/)*</sub>

**Carajo** es una palabra malsonante, un taco, con varios [significados](https://dle.rae.es/carajo) y ninguno positivo. *Vete al carajo* es una espresión muy despectiva.

<sub>*[Origen de la palabra carajo](https://nauticajonkepa.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/origen-de-la-palabra-carajo/)*</sub>

### Carajoles

Contracción de – ¿Qué **carajo les** pasa?–

### Caracoles

> Este vocabulario en su etimología viene de «caramba» como un eufemismo de la interjección «carajo» con el mismo significado

<sub>*Fuente [definiciona.com](https://definiciona.com/caracoles/)*</sub>

A mi entender, el origen de la interjección *caracoles* va ligado al reemplazo de solo una consonante en *carajoles*. Respecto a su uso, todos coinciden con la primer parte del siglo XX:

> Según el Diccionario de la Real Academia, caracoles es equivalente a caramba, y denota extrañeza o enfado; pero no es una expresión que se utilice en la actualidad. Sí se usaba en los años 40 y 50 con cierta frecuencia. Un ejemplo tardío lo encontramos, siguiendo en el mundo cinematográfico, en la película Pan, amor y Andalucía, dirigida por Javier Setó en 1958 y protagonizada por Vittorio de Sica y Carmen Sevilla. En ella, Vittorio de Sica, en el papel de Antonio, emplea la interjección que nos ocupa.

*Fuente [Centro Virtual Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/trujaman/anteriores/septiembre_04/08092004.htm)*

Answer (score 1):

En etimología hay que tener siempre presente que el origen de las palabras es una cosa y las representaciones mentales, ideas y los distintos aspectos a ellas asociados pueden dar lugar a nuevas acepciones, nuevas relaciones e incluso a nuevas palabras. Así pues y desde mi punto de vista, la cuestión más importante y en la que debemos centrarnos en esta deriva del término, es como la voz "**caracoles**" paso a **¡caracoles!** **como interjección**, pues decir, como lo hacen muchos autores, que equivale a ¡caramba!, ¡carajo!, ¡cáspita!... ni nos dice, ni nos descubre, ni avanza nada.

Este **¡caracoles!** como interjección y según las acepciones que los distintos diccionarios indican, puede expresar entre otras; *sorpresa, enfado, extrañeza, cabreo, molestia, admiración*...

De este modo la cuestión a modo de pregunta sería, ¿ *qué algo puede hacer o ser, que origine conductas tan contradictorias y dispares a la vez* ?, y así, se pase de la sorpresa al enfado, o de la extrañeza y cabreo a la admiración, pues como interjección "**¡caracoles!**" encierra todas estas equivalencias a la vez.

Tampoco se nos escapa que muchas de las interjecciones existentes expresan esas mismas conductas a partir de otras palabras como, ¡Caray!, ¡Cáspita!, ¡Diablos!, ¡Vaya!..., sin embargo, de ser así ¿ qué razón o motivación se habría dado, para que apareciese "caracoles", y con ello, se incorporara elevándolo hasta convertirlo en una **interjección** a través de la cual se expresaran tales emociones ?

Recordemos que para la RAE *Interjección* es;

> 1. f. Gram. Clase de palabras invariables, con cuyos elementos se forman **enunciados exclamativos,** **que manifiestan impresiones,
>    verbalizan sentimientos** **o realizan actos de habla apelativos**.

En el gran periplo para comprender, no solo la palabra "caracoles", sino su paso a **¡caracoles!**, me tope con un diccionario de voces cubanas de *Estéban Pichardo y Tapia*, y dentro de la palabra "caracol", hacia mención expresa a un antiguo juego llamado "caracoles" donde se utilizan los caracoles como dados para jugar y dice así;

[image]

---

Mi pregunta es entonces, ¿no es el juego en general, donde se realizan y se expresan exclamaciones, se manifiestan impresiones o se verbalizan sentimientos y emociones cuando se gana o se pierde?

¿ No es en el juego y en las suertes, donde se pueden conocer y dar todos esos sentimientos encontrados, y que a su vez, son los que encierran las equivalencias de todas esas mismas conductas y emociones de *sorpresa, enfado, extrañeza, cabreo, molestia, admiración*?

¿No puede proceder "**¡caracoles!**" **como interjección**, de una expresión originada al echar la suerte o de la recreación de este mismo antiguo juego con caracoles?

"**¡caracoles!**"